# Handle touch event of view that is added in Window Manager

Tags: android

I am trying to handle the touch event for View that is added in the WindowManager using:
WindowManager.addView(View, LayoutParams).

Call that view is MyView. This view has 2 part, 1 that is clickable and the other is not

What I want is when user touchs the clickable part then the MyView will handle the touch event. If user touches the unclickable part, then the event will send through like there is no MyView there.

What I have tried is when user touch the clickable part I update the layout params flag to NOT_FOCUSABLE, then the touch event is handled by MyView.
When user touch the unclickable part, I set the layout params flag to NOT_TOUCHABLE, then the touch event is sent to underneath content. But this time, MyView is no long receive the touch event due to this layout params flag, so I have no chance to reset the flag.

I have no idea to address the problem. Anyone has an idea, please share. Thanks

Comment: Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Seems there is no solution. :|

Comment: for security reasons windowmanagers can't receive touch/key events

Comment: if u want to be able to handle events for the windowmanager and make it "appear" as if theres no background around it you need to put it in its own transparent activity, that way u can consume events

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to add root ViewGroup (e.g. FrameLayout) into the your windowManager. Then, add all views you need to show into the root. Root will consume  all touch events and send them to the child views.
Sorry if I made some mistakes - English isn't my native language.